# How to add "+" button to the menu of a navigation in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a todo app, where user will be able to see all projects in the navigation menu, but I would like to make a "+" (plus) button in that menu, that will add another project to the database and user will be able to see a new project in the navigation menu.

As an example of such a thing, I provide [a screenshot from Todoist application:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFZs6.png)

However, I have no idea how to actually implement it.

My code for nav menu looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_group_one"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
</group>
...

<group
       android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_group_two"
       android:checkableBehavior="none">
       <item android:id="@+id/menu_project_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_project_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/project_1" />
</group>


</menu>
```

And my activity_main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.time.MainActivity">


    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use app:actionLayout for that :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navId"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_ID"
    android:title="Name"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/youritemlayout"

    />
```

Then you can create your "youritemlayout.xml" with your menu item content and your "+" button.